# How to filter rows in which at least a defined number of observations is greater than a specific value?

Tags: filter, subset, rows

I have a data frame with 9 columns and many rows. I want to filter all the rows that have observations greater than 3.0 in **at least** 3 columns. Which conditional statements should I use to subset my data frame?

Since I am a n00b, I only came up with this:
`data_frame[data_frame > 3,]`

Obviously, this gives me all the rows for which all values are > 2, regardless of what I actually need.

Thanks!

Comment: Please tag your language which is one of the most important items for any SO question.

Answer (score 1):

I figured that you could also combine logical operators:

> data[rowSums(data>2)>=3,]

Like this, you can subset from a data frame the rows for which the sum of observations (higher than 2) occurs three or more times. And no specification for the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Logical operator, in this case, the brain. I used the `sum(rowSum(data))>x` # x =sum of the limit value times columns available.